# Como remover class de um campo criado dinamicamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando remover uma class de um label criado dinamicamente pelo handlebars,

Porem não estou conseguindo acha o label com o id dele;

No console se passo o idLabel ele retorna o id certo.

```
"9-hb_usuario-label"
```

Mas quando tento fazer

```
$('form#hb_form').find(idLabel)
```

Para remover a class ele não faz.

```
$('form#hb_form').find('input').each(function () {

            console.log(!$(this));

            var idLabel = $(this).attr('name') + "-label";

            if (idLabel != "undefined-label") {
                if ($(this).valid()) {
                    $('form#hb_form').find(idLabel).removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
                }
                else {
                    $('form#hb_form').find(idLabel.text()).removeClass('hide');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O find funciona de forma similar ao seletor jQuery. Você precisa definir que é um id, senão, ele buscará por tags com aquele nome. Ou seja, deve iniciar com sustenido (`#`):

```
$('form#hb_form').find('#' + idLabel);
```

Entretanto, como id's são (devem ser) únicos, e se você quer manipular, assim se torna mais fácil:

```
$('#' + idLabel).removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
```

Ou, se você não abre mão de ser mais específico:

```
$('form#hb_form #' + idLabel).removeClass('hide').addClass('hide');
```